# How to call a Java Script function from a html button placed inside a php script?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I have a code where an html button is supposed to call a function that changes the style of an element as a way to display it because it is hidden by default.
The button is located inside a php code that requires a condition in order to show the button. The button is not working when it is clicked.
I have tried it outside of the php code and it calls it's function properly so it have to be something with the php code...

```
<?php 
            if($_SESSION['privilege'] == "Standard User"){
                echo "<a href='index.php'><button class='userbtn'>Index</button></a>
                <a href='#'><button class='userbtn'>Check Orders</button></a>
                <a href='#'><button class='userbtn'>Add Order</button></a>";
                exit;
            }
            else if($_SESSION['privilege'] == 'Administrator'){
                echo "<a href='index.php'><button class='userbtn'>Index</button></a>
                <a href='#'><button class='userbtn'>Check Orders</button></a>
                <a href='#'><button class='userbtn'>Add Order</button></a>
                <button class='userbtn' onclick='callReg();'>Add User</button>";
                exit;
            }
            else{
                echo "<a href='index.php'><button class='userbtn'>Index</button></a>";
                exit;
            }
            ?>
```

I expected it to work as it was working outside the php code but it simply doesn't work when it is placed inside the php

Comment: why do you have `exit` there? That will stop the rest of the PHP script from executing, so that button will be the last thing in the document. In particular, if the link to the JS script where `callReg` is defined is after that, it won't be there.

Comment: Why do you have buttons in anchor tags? That makes no sense. Also, there's no identifier on any of the anchor tags or the buttons, so how would you know which has been clicked? (except from the last that has an onclick-attribute)

Comment: @RobinZigmond all that the page is consisted of is a single php script that have 3 different statements each to be executed if it fulfills the required condition after the condition is fulfilled the script should stop running, everything coming afterwards is not needed once a condition is fulfilled.

Comment: A web page consists of valid HTML. You should have more HTML code than just a button on the page. Are you calling this PHP script via AJAX?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i am trying to make the entire web page responsive using % as width measurement and vh as height measurement (there must be a better way to do it but since i am not a css expert that is the way i found) and now the buttons are placed inside of a sidebar element which is only 20% of the entire page width. When i give a button 100% width value it's size is as big as the sidebar and on resize as the sidebar resizes the buttons resize too, when i try to achieve the same thing with an anchor tag only then the buttons are taking around 40% of the page width, # is temporary

Comment: @Dharman no I am not using Ajax, I am not familiar with what it is how it is supposed to be used and how it might come handy in my situation

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't make much sense. You can style both anchor tags and buttons how ever you want. If the button doesn't look correct when not inside of an anchor tag, then use CSS to fix it.

Comment: Maybe try posting the full PHP code. We would have a bigger picture of what your doing and maybe we could help you more. That `exit` seems really wrong, and your HTML tags make no sense. Try to put in the question at least a reproducible example.

Comment: When i create a clickable link that looks like a button using an anchor tag i have a problem with the width, however the css and how the buttons are created  is not my problem right now but the button dysfunctionality is. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of a button inside a link? I can't imagine how it should work properly. Have you checked with a browser console, what is outputted to the browser?

Comment: It works properly i have tested it, anyway those buttons are not my problem but the one that is supposed to call a script is...code updated

Comment: This update raises more questions. Please remove all of these `exits` first. Nothing after the exit is executed so your `</div></div></body></html>` is gone forever. I can't see an element with ID `regPlaceholder` in your HTML. Are you missing an element or an ID attribute somewhere?

Comment: That is being printed on the index page, the index page includes the sidebar

Comment: What? If you include this HTML page into another you cannot have multiple HTML boilerplate tags i.e. HEAD, BODY, HTML. Remove `exit` and your totally invalid HTML should be transferred fully to the browser. But you should fix your HTML first before you start with JS or PHP.

Comment: ...and where do you start your PHP session? Which of the 3 files is the one you included?

Comment: @Dharman - This is a rabbit hole that will swallow you if you keep digging :-) I'm out...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know, I was meant to go shopping, but I really don't want to leave the house. :D

Comment: It is into the header since it is present everywhere, my idea is for this to have few different functions but everything should be happening on the index file... i am going to fix the html right away but everything was working perfectly fine before i placed the button inside the php (just to know it)

Comment: Because of the `exit`!

Comment: Yes, it was the exit, it is working now, thank you! I thought that the exit have a similar function as the break in a javascript switch statement

Comment: On a side note: I have started learning PHP and HTML just like you some time ago. I was also doing spaghetti code and getting lost all the time. Try to think of PHP as a template language. Write HTML and fill in the data using PHP. Don't redirect all the time and don't finish the script prematurely if you are not redirecting. You should probably take a look at a proper framework like Laravel. I recommend to use PDO rather than mysqli, because it is easier to use. Read about prepared statements and web security too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `exit` statements from your PHP code. What the exit does is it stops the execution of the script. If the file was included in another in stops the execution of the whole script, and not just the included file.

[`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

An example:

File1.php:

```
<html>...
Some code here...
<?php 
    include 'file2.php';
?>
Some other HTML code...
</html>
```

File2.php:

```
<?php 
exit;
?>
```

Then the output of the execution of file `File1.php` would end right where the include is. The part `Some other HTML code...</html>` would never be outputted to the browser, because the script stopped halfway through.